# Close Parent div and ul on click that shares another on click container but keeps unwanted li

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, button

I added a span that overlays the container it's supposed to close. It does this fine, but if I click this closing span, it opens the li and closes the parent span and ul but keeps the li open (tried adding li to the .fadeout didn't work).
Attaching my fiddle didn't come out how I expected so i will attach my code here:

JS

```
 var main = function () {

    var recipeArray = ['drink', 'firstCourse', 'mainDish', 'dessert'];
    var recipeArrayLength = recipeArray.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < recipeArrayLength; i++) {

        var $checkBoxes = document.createElement('div');
        $checkBoxes.setAttribute("class", "checkBoxes");
        var $recipePicContainer = document.createElement('span');
        $recipePicContainer.setAttribute("class", "recipePicContainer");



        function makeRecipePic() {

            var recipe = document.createElement("IMG");
            recipe.setAttribute("src", "../images/grasshopper-cocktail.jpg");
            recipe.setAttribute("class", "recipe");
            $recipePicContainer.appendChild(recipe);
        }
        var $deleteRecipe = document.createElement('span');
        $deleteRecipe.setAttribute("class", "fa fa-times-circle", "aria-hidden", "true");
        $recipePicContainer.appendChild($deleteRecipe);

        $($deleteRecipe).click(function(){
            $(this).parents('span', 'ul').fadeOut();
        });

        makeRecipePic();

        var mainContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('mainContainer');
        mainContainer[0].appendChild($checkBoxes);

        var $div = document.createElement('div');
        $div.innerHTML = 'CockTails';
        $recipePicContainer.appendChild($div);
        $checkBoxes.appendChild($recipePicContainer);

        var $recipes = document.createElement("ul");
        var $checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('checkBoxes');

        var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
        x.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");

        for (var j = 1; j <= 6; j++) {
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            li.className = "ingredients";
            li.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");


            var a = document.createElement("a");
            a.innerHTML = "Ingredient " + j;

            li.appendChild(a);
            $recipes.appendChild(li);
        }
        var b = document.createElement("li");
        li.innerHTML = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";
        li.className = "Instructions";

        $checkboxes[i].appendChild($recipes);
    }
    $('.recipes').hide();
    $('<input type="checkbox" value="1" />').prependTo(".ingredients");
    $('.mainContainer .recipePicContainer').click(function () {
        $(this).next('ul').toggle("slow").toggleClass('selected');

    });
};
$(document).ready(main);
```

CSS

```
.fa-times-circle:before {
    content: "\f057";
    position: relative;
    left: 28px;
    bottom: 125px;
    color: white;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
 }
```

HTML

```
<body>

<div class="mainContainer col-md-12 col-xs-12">

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: The code is incomplete: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $recipePicContainer is not defined` [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hk0t9g1j/1/)

Comment: We can't guess what the rest of your HTML looks like.  You say, "...the parent span and ul but keeps the li open..." I don't see where the `ul` or `li` are being created, or what `$recipePicContainer` is.

Comment: sorry, tried o make it less dense, I'll edit it in now